# Interpretations of $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$

Tags: physics, infinity

I am trying to understand the physical sense of the mathematical construct $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$

Suppose we have a function $f(x)$ representing some physical construct depending on a "quantity" $x$ and a function be $g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{f(x)}$

Now I understand mathematically it is not possible to define $g(x)$ when $f(x) = 0$ or $f(x) = \infty$ as they are deemed indefinite. But shouldn't there definition be subject to the definition of the construct $\infty$ ?

in physics various times we define infinite length as simply a very big length compared to a very small length (say infinite solenoid for calculation of field at center of a very long solenoid) in such cases inifinity as I see, seems to be just a big number which would simply give $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ as $1$

Is my line of thought correct ? Is it true that for a physical manifestation of constructs such as $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ we need to define the physical nature $\infty$ ?

What would be the result when we define $\infty$ as the distance at which observable fields of particles (say gravitational field of point mass m) becomes $0$ ?

If there is actually a difference in the mathematical and physical manifestations, then why is that ?

Comment: $\infty$ is not a constant so $\infty - \infty$ is not defined as zero or any other number and $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ isn't defined either.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, in mathematics, "$\infty$" is just a symbol. It is not a number nor an object, and we cannot use it in formulas, meaning you cannot divide with it or add and subtract it. As a symbol, it is used if a value exceeds all bounds, for example the limit of $1/n$ as $n$ goes "to infinity" is zero.

Another way it is used is when a function (or, similarly, a sequence) $f(x)$ has the property that for any upper bound $M$, the value $f(x)$ is greater than $M$ for $all$ values $x$ from some point on. In that case, we write $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x) = \infty$. Be careful, as this "equals" sign does NOT mean the equality of two real numbers. As standard limits go, the limit of $f(x)$ does NOT exist and is definitely NOT a real number.

It's even more risky to try and perform calculations with $\infty$. For example, you say that you feel like $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ should be $1$, and in fact, if you take $f(x)=g(x)$ such that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x) = \infty$, that's what you get if you calculate the limit of $f(x)/g(x)$. Howerver, take $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = 2x$. Now, with some dodgy algebra, you have

$$
1 = \frac{\infty}{\infty} = \frac{\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)}{\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}g(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x}{2x}=\frac{1}{2}
$$
which you probably agree is not right.

Comment: Can we actually input $\infty$ as argument for $x$ ? Or does it make no sense ?

Comment: If you and everybody reading whatever you write agree that when you write $f(\infty)$ you really mean $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)$, then of course you can write $f(\infty)$. However, it is vital you keep in mind this is only a shortening of some notation. It is still necessary to realize that $f(\infty)$ is a limit and may therefore not exist or be infinite.

Comment: No I mean directly using $\infty$ and not just limiting value. The question arises [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/82536/electric-field-lines-density/82540?noredirect=1#comment199014_82540). People are talking about **literally** $\infty$ field lines !

Comment: $\infty$ _CAN_ be an object - it's called the extended real number line. In that case then $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = \infty$ is actually real _bona fide_ equation of real, bona fide objects and this is actually, topologically and geometrically, a quite elegant thing to do. BUT, when you go to this, $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ is NOT defined, just as $\frac{1}{0}$ is not defined in ordinary real numbers. This is because it is in fact not consistent to augment the real number line in this way and have both that all the usual rules of arithmetic hold _and_ that all operations are defined.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer True. Rather than "in mathematics", I should say "In standard analysis".

Comment: That is, it leads to contradictions. Thus something has to give - either you reject some of the rules of arithmetic ("Wheel theory" is a possible, if obscure, way to do this), _or_ you leave some things undefined. The latter approach is the one usually taken. The former rather actually seems to break some of the elegance in the system because the new arithmetical laws are no longer so sweet. While the latter, what it lacks in "completeness", makes up for in geometric elegance.

Comment: @5xum : I thought extended line was part of "standard" analysis, if by that you mean in opposition to "non-standard" analysis. Non-standard analysis is a whole different ball of wax altogether that isn't just adjoining two elements to the line but drilling into mathematical logic, model theory so as to play sleight of hand with the foundations of analysis in order to make analysis happen without doing analysis (in the usual $\epsilon$-$\delta$ sense, limits, etc.).

Comment: @The_Sympathizer Serves me right for using an overloaded word like "standard". I wanted to say "introductory", I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Symbols like $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ and $\infty - \infty$ are often used informally to classify "types" of expressions in a limit.
However, they don't reveal anything about the value of the limit.

For example:
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2x}{x}=2$$
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x^2}{x}=\infty$$
And notice that both are "classified" as $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.

Regarding the symbol $\infty$ itself appearing in relations (Real numbers for simplicity):
$\cdot =\infty$ is just a shorthand notation for "$\cdot$ is greater than any real number".
$\cdot <\infty$ is just a shorthand notation for "$\cdot$ is some real number".

Comment: And $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x}{x^2} = 0$ is another limit of "type" $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since every strictly positive number multiplied with infinity is infinity, and infinity times infinity is also infinity, it follows that $\dfrac\infty\infty$ can be **any** strictly positive value on the [extended real axis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line) $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$, which is why the operation is [undefined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form). The same reasoning applies to $\infty-\infty$.

Comment: It's actually quite funny, because $\infty = \infty$ is a true statement. That means that if $a = a$ it does not necessarily  mean that $a / a = 1$ (only if $a$ is neither real nor rational or anything like that, it's just funny to realize).